# Need magic php code-formatter

Tags: php, ide, code-formatting

Yes, question sounds strange. But I have a big code that wasn't written by my own and contains a lot of while loops and if statements and therefore a lot of braces. WHat I need is the automatic code rebuilding like MS Visual Studio does - no matter where I placed open-brace it will move at right place when I write close-brace. For example:

```
//I write:
function func()
{
if(//some statement)
{
echo('hello world');
}
}

//It will look like this:
function func()
{
    if(//some statement)
    {
       echo('hello world');
    }
}
```

Comment: It is called code formatting. Any decent IDE that supports PHP should do it. I personally use Netbeans. Question itself might be off-topic though...

Comment: phpstorm if you can pay, netbeans if not.

Comment: @Mikk Does really Netbeans do it??

Comment: @Daria yes it does, I use it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) is a free IDE that has the ability to format your code.